# R: Suppressing output in RStudio console (code and warnings)

Tags: r, io, rstudio

I'm working on an R script that is quite long and will eventually have to be used by other people.  I don't want RStudio to spit back every line of code to me when I'm running the script, because it is quite messy.  Ideally, I want to write my own output to console that is more user-friendly, such as progress updates or custom warning/error messages.

Is there a way to do this?  I tried using sink() to send my output somewhere else, but that only got rid of the output created by my code and not the output of code itself.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps `source` is what you are looking for? It will by default not echo the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `suppressWarnings()` to hide warnings.

```
> log(-1)
[1] NaN
Warning message:
In log(-1) : NaNs produced
> suppressWarnings(log(-1))
[1] NaN
```

`try(call, silent = TRUE)` for code that might throw errors.

```
> 1/"1"
Error in 1/"1" : non-numeric argument to binary operator
> try(1/"1", silent = TRUE)
```

There are also `suppressPackageStartupMessages()` and `suppressMessages()`.